# CK Editor (Version 5) paste screenshot not working for react js

Tags: .net, reactjs, ckeditor4.x, ckeditor5

CK Editor (Version 5)  paste screenshot not working for react js.

Comment: Not able to paste any screenshot in ck editor.

Comment: Please add code samples.

Answer (score 0):

In CKeditor 5, you can paste image from clipboard (I had already tested it when I see your post) but you need a backend to store the image's URL and return to the front end to display this image.

With my case, I use simpleUploadAdapter to store and return the Image URL with these configuration's (in backend):

```
{
    "uploaded": true,
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1/uploaded-image.jpeg" <-- this URL is send back to frontend
}
```

You can checkout doc here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor5-simple-upload

Finally, make sure you have these plugins in CKEditor:

> CKFinder, EasyImage, Image, ImageUpload, PasteFromOffice,
> SimpleUploadAdapter

In front-end (your React App), add simpleUploadApdapter Configure like this:

```
<CKEditor
            editor={ClassicEditor}
            data={...}
            onInit={(editor) => {}}
            config={{
              simpleUpload: {
                uploadUrl:
                  "https://your-back-end-API-uploading",
              },
            }}
            onChange={...}
```

Comment: import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import ClassicEditor from 'ckeditor5-classic-plus';
config={{
                  simpleUpload: {                                                     
                                uploadUrl: "http://example.com",                                                       
                                                    }
                                                }}/>
Error - While pasting screenshot gettting error could not upload images.
code link - https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor5-build-classic-simple-upload-adapter

Comment: Hi Sandip Thank u very much , please provide your input.